# installing opencv and javacv

Tags: java, javacv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to use opencv 3.0  in java to detect hand movements. Does opencv 3.0 comes bundled with javacv or do i have to install the corresponding javacv ?

ps:No javacv version seems to match with opencv3.0

Comment: http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html

Answer (score 0):

[JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv)'s OpenCV version covered by [javacpp-presets](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets). Latest version of javacv uses OpenCV 3.0.

You may check it from javacv's [pom.xml](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/pom.xml), to see its dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
  <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-${javacpp.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Javacpp-presets opencv readme file: [JavaCPP Presets for OpenCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/blob/master/opencv/README.md)